# OpenLayers анимация трека

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Делаю трек на карте примерно [так](http://jsfiddle.net/t1nk/2FA6k/) (я имею ввиду, - используя **`OpenLayers`** ***`PointTrack`***).
Нужно, чтобы трек выводился не сразу, а рисовался постепенно или по нему двигался какой-то векторный объект (последнее будет даже лучше, ведь на векторную точку можно повесить любое изображение в качестве его пиктограммы на карте).

Возможно ли такое сделать?
И если возможно, то как (хотя бы в какую сторону копать)?

P.S. понятно, что можно взять точки из которых формируется трек и по ним в самому протащить что угодно, но меня интересует именно возможно это сделать средствами *`OpenLayers`*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я знаю в 2.12 до сих пор это не реализовано.
Вижу только решения с таймером - не важно, писать ли плагин для OpenLayers или свою функцию. По таймеру добавлять в линию трека точки. Или создать для слоя Rule управляющий видимостью точек по бинарному атрибуту и по таймеру включать видимость очередной точки через этот атрибут, если трек отображается множеством точек.

Comment: Спасибо, именно так уже и сделал - протащил точку по треку, а под ней и сам трек нарисовал как раз добавлением точек к нему.  
Не красиво, но работает!  
А раз работает, то как говорится - не трогай...  
Если найду более красивое решение - отпишусь.